# What is a Tetris Word™?

Tags: cipher, pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Tetris Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Tetris Words™ | Not Tetris Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| STOP | NONSTOP |
| FLAME | FIRE |
| HIJACK | TERRORISM |
| BACKWARD | FORWARD |
| POETRY | ARTICLE |
| CHILD | PARENT |
| YOUTUBE | TWITCH |
| WRESTLE | SUMO |
| CARCASSONNE | PROVENCE |
| JACKPOT | MONSTER |
| WAVERS | STALLS |
| FLAG | FLAGSHIP |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Tetris Words™,Not Tetris Words™
STOP,NONSTOP
FLAME,FIRE
HIJACK,TERRORISM
BACKWARD,FORWARD
POETRY,ARTICLE
CHILD,PARENT
YOUTUBE,TWITCH
WRESTLE,SUMO
CARCASSONNE,PROVENCE
JACKPOT,MONSTER
WAVERS,STALLS
FLAG,FLAGSHIP
```

Hint 1

> In 2018 Classic Tetris World Championship(CTWC), Joseph Saelee has defeated Jonas Neubauer who is the 7 championship winners in previous 8 CTWC tournaments

Hint 2

> Joseph Saelee used Hyper-**___** technique to beat the opponent in the first time

Comment: ooh, another one :00

Comment: I love this series :P

Comment: Is JACKPOT definitely a Tetris word? I think I've identified a pattern which matches every word (Tetris and Non-Tetris) except for JACKPOT.

Comment: Examined JACKPOT is Tetris word :) (Maybe I'll produce more example later.)

Comment: Just to let you know, even with the new words, JACKPOT is still the only word I can't get to match.

Comment: i know the answer to second hint but cant proceed hahhaha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Tetris Word is such that

> If we highlight its corresponding letters on a Tap Code Table (as shown below), there will be four squares which form an isolated tetris piece (not part of a bigger polyomino as happens with NONSTOP).
>  [image]

Why didn't I get this sooner

> I had figured out the essential idea previously but was instead using a [Polybius Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybius_square).
>  As it turns out, all the same words work (both Tetris and Non-Tetris) except for JACKPOT.
>  It was hint #2 which put me in the right direction: "Joseph Saelee used Hyper-**tapping** technique to beat the opponent in the first time"

Comment: You just nailed it :P

Comment: Hypertapping is not how I roll.

Answer (score 2):

**PARTIAL ANSWER**

A Tetris Word™ always contains

> at least one pair of letters that are alphabetically-consecutive.  For example, POETRY has O+P, YOUTUBE has T+U, and FLAME has both E+F and L+M.

But some of the Not Tetris Words™ also have the same property, so this isn't a sufficient condition.

Comment: Need something related to Tetris~ Keep going :P

Comment: Could it have something to do with the letter-names of the tetris pieces (O, I, Z, etc)? My strategy would have worked if it weren't for "BACKWARD" :<

Comment: @oAlt Nice try~ related to tetris pieces is correct :P
Hint will be posted later hours~ Keep going!